# Prevent NSTextField from inserting commas when setting intValue

Tags: objective-c, nsstring, nstextfield

In my app I have an NSTextField into which the user can type a value for "Year". This works fine and I save the value off to a file as an integer. However, when I read this value back and place it back into the text field for editing, like so:

```
YearTextField.intValue = dataFromFile.year;
```

The year is comma separated, so an original value of 2020 appears as:  2,020

I know I can stringWithFormat the value into an NSString and then set the stringValue of the NSTextField, but is there a more straightforward way to simply tell YearTextField to not insert commas when setting the value?

Thanks!

Comment: Does the text field have a number formatter?

Comment: You probably have a number formatter and it's configured for readable integer values. Set the formatter's `hasThousandSeparators` property to `false` and you should be OK.

Comment: This is where I am kid of confused. As far as I know, the field doesn't have a text formatter. The field was created as a text field in Interface and I didn't add any code specific to text formatters.  Is there some sort of indicator I should be looking for in Interface Builder?

Comment: You probably want to set the string value.  By setting the int value, you are asking for a numeric value, which gets default numeric formatting.